# How to send push notification to specific user using GCM and phonegap-plugin-push

Tags: cordova, ionic3, phonegap

Is there is any way to send push notification to specific user on android cordova apps?

I followed the tutorial to send push notification from : 
https://codesundar.com/lesson/phonegap-plugin-push/

but it doesn't explain about how to send the push message to specific user

Answer (score 0):

You can find it here: [Push notifications](http://docs.phonegap.com/tutorials/develop/push-notifications/)

Starting with PhoneGap CLI release 6.2.0 and PhoneGap Developer App release 1.6.2, you can now test push notification functionality **without** needing to set up a Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) project for Android or an Apple Push Notification Service (APNs) certification for iOS.

Comment: im using pure cordova, is it okay to use the phonegap tutorial?